# Calendar events from particular Email ID

Tags: android, android-calendar

I have an requirement to fetch events from a specific email id which is synchronized with my mobile calendar.

I can able to fetch all events irrespecitive of specific email id.

How to fetch events from specific mail id. Any help should be great help for me.

```
public ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Multimap<String, String> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();



    public ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                .query(
                        Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[]{"calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"}, null,
                        null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        //endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {
            String test = cursor.getString(0);
            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));
            startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
           // endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
            multimap.put(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))),
                    getTime(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }

    public String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }

    public String getTime(long milliSeconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "hh:mm:ss");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On a particular gmail we may have a more than one `calenders` and their events. so one is the `primary calender` and others are `secondary calenders`. you can inlist all the calenders of user(gmail) and get all the events of each particular calender using google calender api. here is some common operations i have done in past days may it help you in some ways.

[link to github](https://github.com/chnouman/QuickStartGoogleCalenderAPI)

hope it will help you.

Comment: It doesnt provide the proper solution

Comment: but it can help you to start with it